# How to read a number and a sentence using Java Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to understand why using Scanner.nextInt() to read a number and then using Scanner.nextLine() to read a sentence does not work as expected. I have the following code where I input a number but it skips listening to the sentence and my program terminates. Could someone explain why this is and what are alternate solutions?

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
    System.out.println(x);
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a different Scanner instance for String receiving and another for Integer

```
Scanner scanNumbers = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scanString = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int x = scanNumbers.nextInt();
    System.out.println(x);

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
    String line = scanString.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have to write scanner.nextLine() after int x = scanner.nextInt();

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
    System.out.println(x);/*be careful, 
    here you write the result of x and below you are going to write the sentence.
    I think you better write 
    System.out.println(x); 
    above 
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");*/ 

    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
   int x = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(x);

    scanner.nextLine();   // skip the newline character

    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(name1);
```

Comment: ops, instead "in.nextLine();" should be "scanner.nextLine();" rather ;)